# React Navigation hide/show navigation bar

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am facing a problem with hiding or showing the navigation bar with ReactNavigation 5.x.

For example if I have a navigation stack with ScreenA, ScreenB & ScreenC. ScreenA shouldn't show the navigation bar, but on moving to ScreenB or ScreenC the bar should be visible. On popping to ScreenA, the bar should no longer be there. I have used the following code, but that makes the bar hidden always. This has to be achieved in both iOS and Android.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Login"
            component={LoginScreen}/>
          <Stack.Screen
            title='Parent Info'
            name='ParentInfo'
            component={ParentInfoScreen}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    )}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each screen also has an options prop so instead of using screenOptions on stack.navigator use options on stack.screen like this:

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen
    options={{headerShown: false}}
    name="Login"
    component={LoginScreen}
  />
  <Stack.Screen
    title="Parent Info"
    name="ParentInfo"
    component={ParentInfoScreen}
  />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Then you can specify by screen